# Force re-reading a data file

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have a data file from which I want to plot odd/even rows seperately, in the same axis.
But the `table` options seem to apply only once, when reading in the data, which only happens once per axis (i.e. after a `\nextgroupplot` the data seems to be read again, or in a new `tikzpicture`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
1 1
2 4
3 3
4 8
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[no markers] table[each nth point=2]{data.dat};
        \addplot[only marks] table[each nth point=2, skip first n=1]{data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

should be:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[no markers] table{
            1 1
            3 3
        };
        \addplot[only marks] table{
            2 4
            4 8
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there an option to force re-reading the data for each `table` command?

[image: result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use `skip first n` key to filter the coordinates in a flexible fashion as it is a `pgfplotstable` key for either reading the table or typesetting it. Instead you can use filters to eliminate the odd/even numbered rows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
1 1
2 4
3 3
4 8
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[no markers,each nth point=2] table {data.dat};

        \addplot[only marks,x filter/.code={
                    \ifodd\numexpr\coordindex+1\relax
                        \def\pgfmathresult{}
                    \fi}
                ] table {data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course with this code you can cook up your own filters (by using `Mod(,)` etc.) so it is doable anyways.

Comment: Ok, I thought the point of the `table` keys was exactly this kind of filtering (like gnuplot's `every <skip>:<start>:…`), so it's just a side-effect?

Comment: @pascal I think it's more of a row downsampling while reading, column creating and/or typesetting the data. As you can see you can introduce the same functionality (or maybe I don't know in case it already exists). I think this is also easy to introduce so you can file a feature request for that.